# Dynamically choosing Python library based on Python version

Tags: python, command-line

I am writing a Python script which needs to run on RHEL 6.x which defaults to Python 2.6 but also should work with the latest Python.  I need to parse command-line arguments, however Python 2.6 only includes optparse which in recent Python has been deprecated in favor of argparse.  Is there a way to dynamically select whether to use argparse or opt parse (I realize it would require two parsing algorithms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import `argparse` first and then use `optparse` if it can't be found:

```py
try:
    import argparse
    # Argparse-specific stuff
except ImportError:
    import optparse
    # Optparse-specific stuff
```

You can also check the python version using `sys.version` or `sys.version_info`.

```py
import sys
if (sys.version_info.major >= 2 and sys.version_info.minor >= 7):
    import argparse
    # ...
else:
    import optparse
```

Or, you could just use `optparse` on all versions, if you do not need the improved features `argparse` has

Comment: I've used the ImportError method in the first example but followed each import with an import to my own module. `import argparse` followed by `import argparseinterface as xparse` This allows the following code to use a standard interface without any concern for version.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with `optparse` for now, *or* install [`argparse` from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) for the Python 2.6 installation.

Don't try to support both just to support two Python versions; save yourself the headache. `optparse` may be deprecated but *still works just fine* when run with Python 2.7. It just has fewer features than `argparse` can offer.

If you have to run on Python 3.x installations too, then you *could* try to support both with an import guard:

```
try:
    import argparse
    # configure argparse
except ImportError:
    import optparse
    # configure optparse
```

but it'd be much easier to just ship with `argparse` as a dependency.